# Merge GIF and PNG using gm/GraphicsMagick/ImageMagick on Node.js

Tags: node.js, image-manipulation

I'm using gm/GraphicsMagick/ImageMagick (https://github.com/aheckmann/gm) to merge multiple images together. Currently I'm trying to merge a .gif  background with a .png foreground.

Supposedly you could do the following on vanilla ImageMagick using the following command:

```
convert bg.gif -coalesce null: fg.png -layers composite output.gif
```

However, I can't quite understand how to do this using the gm node module. If there are other ways to do this, preferably also using node, that's welcome too.

Comment: GraphicsMagick is an early spin-off of ImageMagick and has not kept up with new features that are in ImageMagick. So I suspect that GraphicsMagick does not have this construct. Why can you not just use ImageMagick?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?